# Having issues installing Ubuntu

Tags: installation, toshiba-satellite

It is taking an incredibly long time to try and install and now I am currently waiting at the twitter installation section but the progress bar has gone. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What hardware are you installing it on? What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: A toshiba satellite L650 and trying to install 12.04

Answer (score 1):

These are the times I use the "Alternative" installer. All CLI, same actions. FWIW, if you can boot from a USB stick, installing from a USB can be unbelievably faster than CD.

Answer (score 0):

I have had that type of issue when installing on a virtual machine. Usually it means that the install has stopped responding. The fix is usually to start again.

*This was on a virtual machine not a regular computer. So it may not work for your situation.*